# Sample Space: Why Assume Repetition? - n balls into n cells

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The answer to the question has been given here before: $n\choose 2$$\frac{n!}{n^n}$

But my question is why is the sample space considered $n^n$?

Isn't this technically assuming repetition of the balls into each cell (something not possible by the nature of the question)?

I would think a permutation(n,n) would be the correct approach instead.

Where am I going wrong in my thinking?

For those who have yet to come across the question:
"If n balls are placed at random into n cells, find the probability that exactly one cell remains empty."

Comment: "*Why is the sample space $n^n$... (and not $n!$)?*"  Because it is pointless to ask the question "what is the probability exactly one cell remains empty" if we were only looking at the $n!$ possibilities where every cell gets exactly one ball in it... Of course the probability that exactly one cell is empty if we put exactly one ball in each cell will be zero... there is no calculation needed, just common sense.

Comment: "*Putting balls into cells*" is almost always intended to mean where we in sequence for each ball take the ball and then choose a cell from **all** available cells (*regardless of if there is already another ball in it*) uniformly at random and independently chosen from all other choices and place the ball in that cell.  There are... as alluded to already... $n^n$ different ways in which we can do that with $n$ balls and $n$ cells, and more generally $k^n$ ways for $n$ balls and $k$ cells.

Comment: "*assuming repetition of the balls into each cell*"  Keep track of what is able to be repeated here.  What is being repeated is the *cell*... multiple balls could go into the same cell simultaneously.  A single ball cannot go into multiple cells simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you so much, @JMoravitz! Your third comment accurately captures what I was getting confused by. Instead of taking the ball and choosing the cell, I was taking the cell and choosing the ball. Which of course if cell 1 chose ball A, ball B and ball C, then of course cell 2 could not choose A, B, or C and could only have n-3 choices to choose from. This is why I kept thinking repetition wasn't possible here. What can I do in the future to make sure I do not reverse this way of thinking when answering these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe substituting two different variables will help you to grasp the mechanics of this problem.  So let there be $k$ balls and $n$ cells.  This should be much more clear when there are not $n$ of each.  When $k=n$ and one cell is left empty, then clearly repetition is key to solving the problem; if there could be no repetition then it would be impossible for any cell to remain empty for the case where $k=n$.  Let's look at the case where $k < n$.  Supposing $k=5$ and $n=7$.  Each of the five balls, each distinct (all of different colors), can be placed in a cell in seven ways, and each cell is distinct since the cells are arranged in an order. A ball can be placed in a cell that already has a ball in it, so there is repetition and the placement of one ball does not affect the placement of the ones that follow.  So the number of ways of placing the five balls in seven cells is $7\times7\times7\times7\times7 = 7^5$.  Note that if repetition were allowed, the first cell could be chosen n=7 ways while the second cell could be chosen n-1=6 ways etc.   Now let's suppose $k > n$.  Supposing $ k = 5$ still but now $n = 4$.  Each of the five balls can be placed in a cell in four ways.  It has to be possible to place a ball in a cell that already has a ball in it, or else we would run out of cells.  Each ball is distinct so it isn't the same to put the blue ball in the second cell as it is to put the green ball in the second cell.  So the number of ways of placing the five balls in four cells is $4\times4\times4\times4\times4 = 4^5$.  The general formula for the total number of possible arrangements of $k$ distinct balls in $n$ distinct cells is $k^n$.  When $k = n$ then the total number of possible arrangements could be written as $n^n$.  Now you can change the assumptions, for instance, so that the balls are not distinct but are all of the same color, and update the resulting outcomes.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Gwendolyn Anderson. As I noted in a previous comment, I was getting confused because I was assigning cells to balls (cell 1 gets balls A & B, therefore cells 2 through n cannot get balls A or B, but n-2 balls) instead of balls to cells as you outline here--which indeed does allow for repetition. What can I do in the future to help prevent my mistake of reversing the counting order when answering these types of questions? Thanks

Comment: I am unsure of the difference of assigning a cell to a ball, or a ball to a cell.  Try creating a simplified numerical example, like how can you place $5$ balls in $7$ cells?  And vice versa.  I think what is most tricky about this problem overall is that $k = n$.  That makes it easy to confuse the variables when they are both assigned the same value $n$.   Which one is the count for cells and which one is the count for balls?  So create different variable names (which will each be given the same value $n$), and focus on the key point, in this problem, for one cell to remain empty.